# Very simple question about faker.random in javascript... newbie question

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, faker, generate

I am very newbie in javascript!

I want to be professional in javscript!

I am shame to ask this question, but I cannot find anything about it :(

```
(faker.random.number(89999999) + 10000000)
```

If I am using this faker, what numbers will be generated?

And If I want to generate numbers from 10000000 to  80000000 with faker.random.number

What code will it be?

Thank you!

Sorry for very stupid qeustion.

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to go for a native solution to this question. You can use `Math`, and it's functions to generate a random numbers.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

`min` and `max` are both inclusive.